# Confusing phrase suggestion. "Gates open!"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I recently had a brief Skype chat conversation with someone. Skype tends to automatically suggest a few phrases to use as responses to questions or messages you receive.

So the conversation was like this:

- A: "Can we postpone the meeting by 15 minutes?"
- B: "Hi, yes no worries!"
- A: "Great, thx"

Then Skype suggested three phrases I could use to respond:

1. "No problem!"
2. "My pleasure!"
3. "Gates open!"

Now, (1) makes perfect sense. I guess (2) is also quite OK. But what in the world is (3)?

I'm not a native English speaker and asked some friends but they have no idea, and Google is no help.

Is it a phrase at all in English? The current best hypothesis is that it is a normal expression in this context in a different language which has just been automatically translated to English and suggested. Would anyone be able to verify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be an easter egg of sorts in Skype. In any case, as a native speaker I'll tell you it doesn't make sense as a response here. I found this [relevant conversation on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Skype/status/1042798641537265664):

> George Eastmead @GEastmead Sep 19:
>
> Why does Skype eternally suggest 'Gates open!' as a suggested response to almost anything?!
>   [image]

> Skype @Skype
>   Because "Gates Closed!" sounds so much less inviting! http://msft.social/D7d1tu

That last link leads to [this gif](https://media1.giphy.com/media/fCUEqAAeZG1cSnyfjv/giphy.gif), making it clear it's a reference to Wimbledon.